# Evaluate $\sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{1 + 3 \sqrt{1 + \dots}}}$

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

I was asked to show that the answer is 3. I don't have any idea on how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: This was solved by Ramanujan; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Infinitely_nested_radicals.

Comment: The [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/605363/1) to all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

See this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical (Ramanujan's problem for the 'Journal of Indian Mathematical Society' )